# Issues with pullling Ngrx Entities in Store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I have been developing an app to learn Angular Ngrx Store and Entities. The app used the example app from ngrx/platform as a starting point. [The code and app is here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6nyhnt)

I am trying to use a createSelector to filter out the pomos with a task_id that matches the id of the the selected task. Not being able to do even that, I tried just loading all the pomos into state using the pomo reducer based on EntityAdapter. That doesn't work either. All of my actions are successful including adding a pomo to the store but I can't get them to load. At this point I am just trying to get all of them to load but the ultimate goal is a selector that loads the pomos based on it's task_id. I suspect that the issue is most likely how the State is actually composed but I can't figure out how to do it. Like I said, the action for adding a Pomo to the store works fine but when loading the pomos. It returns empty.

**Here is what i have for my reducers/index.ts**

```js
export interface State {
  search: fromSearch.State;
  tasks: fromTasks.State;
  pomos: fromPomos.State;
  collection: fromCollection.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<any> = {
  search: fromSearch.reducer,
  tasks: fromTasks.reducer,
  pomos: fromPomos.reducer,
  collection: fromCollection.reducer,
};

export const getTasksState = createFeatureSelector<TasksState>('tasks');
export const getPomosState = createSelector(getTasksState, state => state.pomos);


export const getTaskEntitiesState = createSelector(
  getTasksState,
  state => state.tasks
);


export const getPomosEntitiesState = createSelector(
  getTasksState,
  state => state.pomos
);

export const {
  selectIds: getTaskIds,
  selectEntities: getTaskEntities,
  selectAll: getAllTasks,
  selectTotal: getTotalTasks,
} = fromTasks.adapter.getSelectors(getTaskEntitiesState);

export const {
  selectIds: getPomoIds,
  selectEntities: getPomoEntities,
  selectAll: getAllPomos,
  selectTotal: getTotalPomos,
} = fromPomos.adapter.getSelectors(getPomosEntitiesState);
```

Comment: As it is, your question is kinda hard to digest. Are all the elements in your code snippet part of your problem? (like, none of those selectors are working?). Trim your code snippet to only contain whats necessary (remove irrelevant comments + irrelevant code). Rephrase yourself into shorter sentences, otherwise most ppl will just read over and skip your question. I tell you this, cause I was just about to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will do that right away. Thanks.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I edited it down to what I think is my specific issue. I have tried different variations of composing the state in the **reducers/index.ts**. The current version is based off the one writtten for the ngrx platform example app.

Comment: Hi, check my code for feature selectors, it works for me and it is quite the same that you are trying to accomplish, I think: https://github.com/sebastiandenis/Money-PWA/blob/master/src/app/budget/store/reducers/index.ts

Comment: @SebastianDenis. Thanks for this. I went ahead and implemented my solution with ngxs. Your code definitely looks like what I am trying to do so I will go back when I am finished and try this. Thanks.